# Build,Package, Deploy and Attach to all sharpeoint processes with one keystroke?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I would like to know if its possible with visual studio or anyother extension to customize it to do

Build
Package
Deploy
(wait for iis processes to restart)
attach to all sharpeoint processes.

I was playing with vs today and I found there is a command to build and attach to all sharepoint processes.

But it would need deployment before attaching to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simple press F5 in Visual studio, this will do everything(retract, deploy n debug) for you. If you need more I would suggest you to use [CKSDEV](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) i found this really helpfull

Comment: F5 is the worst thing ever because it retracts the solution when you stop debugging. Nobody serious in sharepoint does that.

Comment: I agree with you and that is why i gave you option of CKSDEV. that what we use. Also you can change the default behaviour of F5, right click on your project and in 'properties' select 'sharepoint' tab. here you can change active deployment configuration. most importantly if you have CKSDEV installed then you will have even more options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change deployement process of your sharepoint project in Visual studio setting.
**Go to project property > Sharepoint Tab> change active deployement configuration**
[image]